# Signal Handler return and resume the program execution

Tags: c, linux, signals, powerpc, signal-handling

I am working on legacy application development which involves lot of signal handling and virtulization. I am facing difficult in understading the below mentioned scenario...

### Program flow:

(A) SIGTRAP -> (B) Process -> (C) SIGTRAPHANDLER -> (D) foo() [functional implemented in libfoo] -> (E) message to kernel (thru NETLINK socket)  -> (F) RETURN

```
(A) is the sigtrap signal which is sent to process1 
(B) is the normal user space process 
(C) is the sigtrap handler invoked upon sigtrap signal 
(D) foo() function is invoked under sigtrap handler and the function implemention is in libfoo library
(E) Upon the invocation of foo() function , message is send to query x() data from kernel thru netlink socket
(F) Successful message reply
```

here, at event (F) if the message reply is not received the process (B) is stalled forever which resulted in failure of all other processes which depends on (B).

As far now, I attempted to break the signal using alarm() which didnt help to resume the program execution instead can treat alarm () only as recovery/cleanup stuff.

Could someone help me on how the program execution can be recovered (within process B context) ?

Sorry, if the explnation if not clear and precise.

Platform : Linux, C

```
int main() {

bind_sigtrap_hand(); 
bind_sigalarm_hand();
bind_handler_for_others();

}

bind_sigtrap_hand() {

sa.sa_handler = invoke_me_sigtrap;
if (sigaction(SIGTRAP, &sa, NULL)  != 0)
{
//Error
}
}
bind_sigalarm_hand() {

sa.sa_handler = invoke_me_sigalarm;
if (sigaction(TIMER_SIGNAL, &sa, NULL)  != 0)
{
//Error
}

}

void invoke_me_sigtrap(sig stuff)
{

if (SIGTRAP == sendsys){

sendsyscall();

}
}
```

Here, in above example the sendsyscall () performs X action in kernel memory area which stalls frequently which is under sigtrap. Here , which kind of signal/alarm which help to resume the procees (without kill) to normal execution.

Comment: You should show some source code. Otherwise, your explanation is not clear enough!

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch
Thanks Basile. The end to end code is very big. So tried to capture the pseudo code as in above updated question box. 

Could you/all please help me out here?

Answer (score 0):

Blocking in the signal handler is not a good idea, very difficult to reason about program behavior in that case.

I would suggest that you do the heavy lifting in a separate thread, which is signaled by the signal handler, but the signal handler returns quickly. I created a crude example, based on yours, with mutexes (works in Linux), but preferably a message queue should be used for signaling the handler thread:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <pthread.h>

void sendsyscall() {printf("sendsyscall blocks for a long time\n"); sleep(3); printf("sendsyscall done\n");}
pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
void*thread(void*arg) {printf("in helper thread\n");
for(;;) {
        printf("thread-locking\n");
         pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
        printf("thread-unlocking\n");
         pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
        printf("thread calling the troubled sendsyscall()\n");
         sendsyscall();
         sleep(1);//this is a hack, use msgrcv instead of a mutex
}
}//thread

int main() {
pthread_t thread_id;
printf("MAIN1\n");
pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
pthread_create(&thread_id,NULL,thread,NULL);
printf("MAIN2\n");
bind_sigtrap_hand();
bind_sigalarm_hand();
//bind_handler_for_others();
for(;;) {sleep(1); printf(".");}
}

void invoke_me_sigtrap(int sendsys)
{
        printf("invoke_me_sigtrap(%d)\n",sendsys);
if (SIGTRAP == sendsys) {
        //INSTEAD OF: sendsyscall(); WE DO:
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
        printf("hopefully, sendsyscall() executes in the other thread\n");
        sleep(1);//this is a hack, use msgsnd instead of a mutex
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
        printf("main thread resumes quickly\n");
}
}

//END OF NEW CODE, ORIGINAL SAMPLE FOLLOWS
bind_sigtrap_hand() {
struct sigaction sa;
sa.sa_handler = invoke_me_sigtrap;
if (sigaction(SIGTRAP, &sa, NULL)  != 0)
{
//Error
}
}//bind_sigtrap_hand

#define TIMER_SIGNAL SIGALRM
void invoke_me_sigalarm(int signal) { }
bind_sigalarm_hand() {
struct sigaction sa;
sa.sa_handler = invoke_me_sigalarm;
if (sigaction(TIMER_SIGNAL, &sa, NULL)  != 0)
{
//Error
}

}//bind_sigalarm_hand
```

Comment: `Blocking in the signal handler is not a good idea,...` -->> Calling printf() in the signal handler is not a good idea either...

Comment: @Madaa Kaama : Thanks for the code.. The code was very legacy and there is no chance of pinning the multi threaded programming there. I was looking for some kind of sigaction which will help to interrupt the SIGTRAP and resume the process execution from where it left (last nip) without _exit();

Comment: @wildplasser: precisely same problem. I dont want to be blocked in signal handler for more than say 5 ms.. And also, dont want to terminate the process incase inside signal handler job work is not completed in expected time (5ms) .

Comment: Since the code uses `sigaction()` it is not "very legacy". Since you use sigaction(), you should also take a look at sigsetmask() and sigprocmask() and friends. BTW: if foo() is part of an "external" library, it could be that this library (re)installs it's own signal handlers.

Comment: @wildplasser:Thanks for the reply.. I double checked the foo() library code and no where I could find any signal hand related code.. The code which I doubt really is the netlink socket recv call() ..BTW, if someone could help on how to set alarm() or sched interrupt to get this syscall interrupted.. I attempted sample prog but in which I am not able to resume the program execution under sigtrap instead I took different sigcontext (sigalarm) and have to _exit() the process execution..

Comment: `The code which I doubt really is the netlink socket recv call() .` Show us the code, this is getting nowhere without relevant code.

Comment: @wildplasser, Yes.. I am drafting the code. Meanwhile, could someone help me on generic question that , is there a way out of sigtrap or any sync type of interrupt upon specified timeout ?

Comment: @wildplasser printf()'s are not a part of the solution, they are for debugging only, to be removed in production code.

Comment: @Snake I still feel the efforts to do the processing in the signal handler are misguided, you should probably better try to find a way to extract all required processing into a "normal" environment. E.g. go-language is inherently parallel, but can perform all tasks from a single thread. Maybe you can use a sidekick-process + shared memory, if threads are unavailable?

Comment: @MadaaKaama: thanks.. In parallel , I am in process of doing side-kick step.. which I am the level best to work as the main process will be waitin for the specificd time interval and get out incase of expiry.

Comment: @wildplasser MadannaKaama  Thanks all.. Requesting child to perform the stalling func call addressed my need here... though the cause of stall is yet to be identified and will take some time..